# angular routing not showing inside ng-view

Tags: angularjs, routes

my first post, I have searched but cannot find a solution.

My content from routing cannot be seen in ng-view.

indext.html

```
<html lang="en"  ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="static/js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ng-view></ng-view>

</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.config(['$routeProvider',

function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    console.log("Kom till config");

    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {templateUrl: 'static/partials/mainpage.html',
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
}]);
```

I get no errors and do not know how to troubleshoot, I am thankful for your help.

File structure is

```
C:.
├───.idea
├───.openshift
│   ├───action_hooks
│   ├───cron
│   │   ├───daily
│   │   ├───hourly
│   │   ├───minutely
│   │   ├───monthly
│   │   └───weekly
│   └───markers
├───static
│   ├───css
│   ├───fonts
│   │   ├───font-awesome
│   │   │   ├───css
│   │   │   ├───fonts
│   │   │   ├───less
│   │   │   └───scss
│   │   └───fonts
│   ├───img
│   │   ├───client
│   │   ├───portfolio
│   │   └───team
│   ├───js
│   └───partials
└───templates
    ├───admin
    └───security
```

It is a flask server that gives the resources to the client.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add ngRoute to your module.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);
```

Then use $routeRrovider like this:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
  function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider.
      when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/partial.html'
      }).
      otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/'
      });
   }]);
```

In your index.html use:

```
<div ng-view></div>
```